# NGINX not serving htm files, but serving all other static files

Tags: django, nginx, tinymce, mezzanine

I've been banging away at this for a bit and I'm obviously missing something simple.  I have a Django application I'm serving on nginx.  All the other static files across the application are being served ok, except for some .htm files that are part of the library for the TinyMCE HTML editor.

The path for the file not being served is: 
http://www.myurl.org/static/admin/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/advlink/link.htm/

The nginx log file states the error is:
"/home/deployer/cmp/cml/static/admin/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/advlink/link.htm/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory)"

(Incidentally, I don't know why nginx keeps thinking that file path leads to a directory.)

But, this test file:
http://www.myurl.org/static/admin/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/advlink/tst.html
is served ok.

My config file is:

```
upstream app_server_wsgiapp {
    server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XX.XXX.X.XX;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/XX.XXX.X.XX.access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/XX.XXX.X.XX.error.log info;
     keepalive_timeout 5;

 #nginx serve up static files and never send to the WSGI server
 location /static {
   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   autoindex on;
   alias /home/deployer/cmp/cml/static;
 }

 location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_redirect off;
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
     proxy_pass http://app_server_wsgiapp;
     break;
   }
 }

 #this section allows Nginx to reverse proxy for websockets
 location /socket.io {
   proxy_pass http://app_server_wsgiapp/socket.io;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_buffering off;

   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

 }
}
```

Relevant portions of mime types file:

```
types {
        text/html                               html htm shtml;
        text/css                                css;
        text/xml                                xml rss;
        image/gif                               gif;
        image/jpeg                              jpeg jpg;
        application/x-javascript                js;
        application/atom+xml                    atom;
        ...
      }
```

Any suggestions to get that link.htm to be served?

Update: After trying a few things, I noticed that the nginx error log says: "/home/deployer/cmp/cml/static_proxy/index.html is not found" and the request is coming from: "GET /static_proxy/?u=myurl.org/static/admin/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/advlink/link.htm

(For the record, this isn't my application, I'm helping a teacher friend migrate off Gondor to Linode after her Dev bailed.)

The static_proxy is coming from the tinymce lib.  But, that isn't a problem in dev on my machine.  Everything works great there. I tried adding in this location block, but that was just a flailing guess.

```
location /static_proxy {
         autoindex on;
         root /home/deployer/cmp/cml;
        }
```

If I change the root directive in the above to

```
alias /home/deployer/cmp/cml/static;
```

I get the static directory listing in the pop-up, which seems like an improvement.

Comment: Surely the link is wrong; it shouldn't have a trailing slash.

Comment: That trailing slash is added by the server when I attempt to load that URL without it.  But, if I change the file extension to .html instead of .htm the file loads just fine.

Comment: So what files are in the `/home/deployer/cmp/cml/static/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/advlink/` directory?

Comment: What happens if you set `APPEND_SLASH = False` in your `settings.py`? Nginx won't automatically append a slash unless you have an explicit rewrite, so I suspect Django is doing it for you.

Comment: @RichardSmith advlink file contains: css  editor_plugin.js  editor_plugin_src.js  js  langs link.htm  test.htm  tst.html

Comment: @KeenanLawrence APPEND_SLASH = False has no effect after service nginx reload

Comment: It's a long shot - but try `root /home/deployer/cmp/cml;` instead of the `alias` directive (Note that the last path segment is also removed)

Comment: Richard's suggestion is probably your best bet, as this request won't even hit your Django app. Sorry, I read wrong.

Comment: I posted an update in the original question.  I dug into the logs a bit more and found out a few things.

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same issue with Wordpress-Mailpoet-TinyMCE.

After struggling a bit, I noticed all the files ending with *.htm* or *.html* were not found. When renaming the same file with a different suffix like .jpg or .gif, it get served successfully.
So I finally add a special NGINX directive allowing htm and html files coming from the mailpoet extension.
Here it is :

```
# Mailpoet - tinyMCE quick fix
location ~ /wp-content/plugins/wysija-newsletters/js/tinymce/.*\.(htm|html)$ {
 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
 access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 30d;
}
```

Hope it might help others...

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue getting timymce to work with nginx.

The following link helped me solve the issue. Not sure if it's the best solution but it worked well for what I needed it to do.

https://techvangelist.net/nginx-global-rewrite-issue-js-css-images-not-found/

I was able to get tinymce to work by adding a directive like this...

```
#tinymce fix
location ~ .(mezzanine|tinymce)/(.+)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;
}
```